# Blank screen after a number of mistakes while installing Windows

Tags: hard-drive, windows, bootcamp, partition, screen

TL;DR: I tried to install Windows on an old iMac and failed horribly. Now I am left with a blank screen and hope to recover to a state from which I can either use Mac or Windows.

I have been trying to install Windows on a 2013 iMac and had a lot of problems. I tried to boot Windows off a USB drive that was prepared with a Windows setup help program from the Microsoft website. I had to put this on the USB on a Windows device because using the regular setup files failed because my Mac said the file was too large.

This worked, and I could finally enter the Windows installation program on my Mac. Here, I saw about five partitions, small and large, and tried installing Windows on the one that seemed like the intended partition (all partitions were called partition 1,2,3, etc). I could not install Windows, because the Windows installation program required my drive have a GUID Partition Table (GPT) scheme. So, I tried changing that and the first method I found required shutting down System Integrity Protection.

When I did that, I am not exactly sure if I succeeded to change the disk to the GUID Partition Table (GPT) scheme, but I do know that after that I could only boot into Mac Recovery Mode or Windows Installer. In Disk Utility, it did seem that the drive was GPT.

Because I did not really need a Mac, I just continued to try installing Windows, but it still did not work because "Windows must be installed to a partition formatted as NTFS". To solve this problem, I found somewhere that I should delete all partitions, which might not have been a very smart idea because I deleted half of my hard drive and could not recover this without a file management system (apparently).

After a while, while I was making it harder and harder for myself to get back to the old Mac state (installing OS X kept failing), the iMac even stopped booting into Recovery Mode all of a sudden, leaving me with a blank screen.

Is there anything I can do? I hope someone can help me. I did back up all of my files.

Comment: I have a 2013 iMac with the current Catalina installed on a USB SSD and 64 bit Windows 10 (21H2) installed on the original HDD. The Mac does not have an internal SSD. What drive arrangement do you have? What versions of macOS and Windows do you want installed and on which drives?

Comment: Do you have any other computers available? If so, what models and what operating systems are installed.

Comment: I have a laptop with macOS Monterey, as well as a windows laptop available (owned by a friend). The iMac used el Capitan and only has one internal HDD (1TB but I "removed" half). I tried to install windows 10 home while keeping macOS el Capitan available on the same drive.

Comment: But I can't do anything because the screen remains blank

Comment: Have you tried to boot to [OS X Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-macos-recovery-on-an-intel-based-mac-mchl338cf9a8/mac), then erase the disk and reinstall a version of OS X or macOS?

Comment: OS X Internet Recovery didn't work. Will I be able to erase the disk and install OS X without a working screen?